# I have two dataframe I want the result to be in dd hh:mm:ss using pyspark or pyspark.sql

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frame as shown below I would like to get the difference in the form of `dd hh:mm:ss:SSSS`

```
ID  date_1                      date_2                      date_diff
A   2019-01-09T01:25:00.000Z    2019-01-10T14:00:00.000Z    -1
B   2019-01-12T02:18:00.000Z    2019-01-12T17:00:00.000Z     0
```

I am currently using this query that returns only date difference

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import datediff
df = df.select("slno",datediff('new_time','old_time').alias(diff_time)
```

I want the final dataframe to be in

```
slno  old_time                      new_time                    diff_time
A     2019-01-09T01:25:00.000Z      2019-01-10T14:00:00.000Z    -1 HH:MM:ss:SSSS
B     2019-01-12T02:18:00.000Z      2019-01-12T17:00:00.000Z     0 HH:MM:ss:SSSS
```

how can i achieve this using `pyspark or pyspark.sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the difference between two dates in hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds using Spark SQL, you can use the TIMESTAMPDIFF(), DATEDIFF(), and CONCAT() functions.
Here is the query:

```sql
    SELECT sl_no,
       date_1 AS old_time,
       date_2 AS new_time,
       CONCAT(
               DATEDIFF(date_2, date_1),
               ' ',
               HOUR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_1, date_2)),
               ':',
               MINUTE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_1, date_2)),
               ':',
               SECOND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_1, date_2)),
               '.',
               SUBSTRING(MICROSECOND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, date_1, date_2)), 1, 3)
           )  AS diff_time
FROM df1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substract the two timestamp columns from each other. The result is an interval column and the expected output can be taken from this column using `regexp_extract`:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('diff', F.col('date_2') - F.col('date_1')) \
  .withColumn('diff', F.regexp_extract('diff', "([0-9\s:.]{10,})",0)) \
  .show(truncate=False)
```

Result (test data slightly changed):

```
+---+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|ID |date_1                |date_2             |diff         |
+---+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
|A  |2019-01-09 02:25:01.02|2019-01-10 15:00:00|1 12:34:58.98|
|B  |2019-01-12 03:18:00   |2019-01-12 18:00:00|0 14:42:00   |
|C  |2019-01-12 03:18:00   |2020-01-12 18:00:00|365 14:42:00 |
+---+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
```